# Bootstrap navbar toggle button not working asp.net

Tags: asp.net, navbar

The toggle button does not work when the window is collapsed. I do not know which part is wrong.

I can not tell if JQuery is not running or whether it is a different problem.

```
<link href="~/CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/CSS/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".ttnavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Default.aspx">AS HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse ttnavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/Default.aspx">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">aa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">bb</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked the console to see if you have any errors?

Comment: Shouldn' this line `js/bootstrap.min.js` be `~/js/bootstrap.min.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines of code at the end of the page's body section.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have worked an example of a navbar with a toggle button in ASP.Net so you can copy the code and check it where you have made mistake.Notice that I have created the navbar in a [MasterPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) file. Here is the code

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MySite.master.cs" Inherits="ProjectName.MySite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title></title>


    <link href="Designs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>
    <form id="masterPageForm" runat="server">



            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#collapsingPart" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsingPart">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    </ul>

                       <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                           <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:textbox runat="server" cssclass="form-control"></asp:textbox>
                                <asp:button runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-primary"  text="search" />
                           </div>
                       </div> 

                </div>

            </nav>



        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```